# PHP: add non-numeric value to start of range array in one line

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add "Please choose" to the beginning of this array

```
$enDuration  =   range( 0 , 60);
```

Best would be it all happens in ONE line as it is for a language config file and should stay as clean as possible. Array_combine didn't work for me.

Comment: aren't you able to handle it in HTML or with your framework (if you have one) ?

Comment: $enDuration = array_merge(array('Please choose'), $enDuration);

Comment: $enDuration = array('Please choose') + $enDuration;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_merge`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), like this:

```
$enDuration = array_merge(['Please choose'], range(0, 60));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$enDuration  =   array_merge(array('Please choose'),range( 0 , 60));
```

Works!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$enDuration = range( 0 , 60);
$enDuration = array('Please choose') + $enDuration;
```

or

```
$enDuration = array('Please choose') + range( 0 , 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function like this

```
$enDuration  =   array('Please choose',range( 0 , 60));
print_r($enDuration);
```

also you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$a=array_merge(array('Please choose'),range( 0 , 60));
```

but there is some difference between `array_merge` and `array`, you can check difference in below output,

your desired [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6b68d6edd6c337d8feb966976cbdbfb5f8da9be)

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new `array()` or merge with the array, but you can also just tell PHP to add it to the beginning of the array, and correct the keys automatically.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

```
$enDuration = range(0 , 60); array_unshift($enDuration, "Please choose");
```